# WinDirStat-like control in Delphi

Tags: delphi, vcl

The program WinDirStats (written in C++, see http://sourceforge.net/projects/windirstat/ ) has at the top a control that combines a tree-like structure (The column "Name", first on the left) with other types of data (graphic bar in column "Subtree percentage") and other text columns.

My question is, using Delphi 7, which control should I use to do something like that? It's the tree part that I find more difficult to get right.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The best control for this would most likely be Mike Lischkes Virtual Tree View.

[Developers Homepage](http://www.soft-gems.net/) | [Google Code Page](http://code.google.com/p/virtual-treeview/)

- It's free
- It gives you a tree connected with a list view
- It allows for custom drawing
- It's incredibly flexible
- It's lightning fast

The only downside is that you have to learn a quite different paradigm than most Delphi controls have, but apart from that it is a teriffic control.

I myself have used it in various projects quite successfully and never hit a real roadblock while using it.

Comment: That's a great recommendation, thanks. It certainly looks like it can do everything I need (and a lot more). I will accept this as the answer, but if someone else has different suggestions, please do add them as well, thanks!

Comment: I agree with HalloDu, and would recommend to have a look at the advanced demo in the VST demoes. It gives a quick overview what is possible. (and not even with too much work)

Answer (score 0):

I also prefer Virtual Treeview, but here are some commercial alternatives:

- [ExpressQuantumTreeList](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/VCL/ExQuantumTreeList/)
- [ElTree](http://www.lmdinnovative.com/products/vcl/lmdelpack/desc/screenshots0.php)
- [TTreeList](http://www.tmssoftware.com/site/treelist.asp)